# Making sum 1/n^2 in pyton

Tags: python

Im making a pyton exercise for my uni homework and can't seem to figure it out. I need to make the sum of 1/n^2, n being a value introduced by the user.

Example:

user puts `n=4`

Program Calculates: `1+1/4+1/9+1/16= 1.42361111`

This is what i have so far:

```
num = int(input("n: "))

sum = 0
x=1
while x<=num:
    sum=1/(x*x)
    x=x+1
    
print ("the sum is:" , sum)
```

Comment: You need to *add* on each iteration to the sum, for now you *assign*. Effectively you end up computing the last value, not sum of them

Comment: You aren't summing anything, you're just overwriting `sum` on each iteration of the loop.  Perhaps you want `+=` there.

Comment: Mentioned in a comment in a proposed answer below, but it should `1/(x**2)` not `1/(x**x)`, right?

Comment: Also beware of using names that conflict with python standard names. E.g. `sum()` is a function to find a sum of a collection. But by doing `sum = 0` you no longer can use `sum()` function

Comment: You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name because it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Comment: If you want to please your prof, you can also do something cool like `sum(x**-2 for x in range(1, num+1))`

Comment: That series is a special case of the _Riemann zeta function_ and many scientific libraries provide an implementation for it, for ex [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#module-sympy.functions.special.zeta_functions)

Answer (score 3):

Taking all of the good advice in the comments into an answer:

1. Don't use `sum` as a variable as that's already a function name in Python.
2. You have to add `sum` to itself each iteration, otherwise `sum` is just overwritten each iteration.
3. *(Pointed out in the comments that your version is `x*x` which is the same as `x**2`. So this is a totally moot point.)* I believe your denominator should be `x**2` not `x**x` based on your first paragraph.

---

```
num = int(input("n: "))

output_sum = 0
x = 1
while x <= num:
    output_sum += 1/(x**2)
    x += 1
    
print ("the sum is:" , output_sum)
```

---

```
>>the sum is: 1.4236111111111112
```

Note: I switched from `x = x+1` to the more common form `x += 1`. The same addition using the `+=`operator is being used for your `output_sum` as well.

Comment: works perfectly now. Thank you for your help and patience, im quite new to programing so this really helped me. Take care my friend

Comment: Not a problem! We've all started and struggled through this stuff in the beginning too.

Comment: Btw, on point #3, _"your denominator should be `x**2` not `x**x`"_ - unless it was a quick edit by the OP, they've put `x*x` which is `x**2`, which would be correct. Easy to misread without the correct spacing.

Comment: Sneaky `x*x`. Maybe I saw pre-edit or my brain just didn't catch that and assumed they were attempting something funky like x-to-the-power-of-x. I am WAY behind on my coffee consumption this morning, so that's probably on me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say as following: `sum=sum + 1/(x*x)`

```
num = int(input("n: "))

sum = 0
x=1
while x<=num:
    sum=sum + 1/(x*x)
    x=x+1
    
print ("the sum is:" , sum)
```

Comment: There is `+=` for that.

Comment: Furthermore, shouldn't it be `sum += 1/(x**2)` not `x**x`?

Comment: From the question, it should be `x*x` to get the result 1.42. when you say `x**x`, the result is going to be 27 when x = 3, other than 9.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by calculating the sum of a generator expression (which is about 3 times faster than other methods using `while` that have been proposed):

```
num = int(input("n: "))

result = sum(1/i * 1/i for i in range(1, num+1))
    
print ("the sum is:" , result)
```

Comment: no need for the extra parentheses inside `sum()` though

Comment: @JussiNurminen yeah, just been testing that, it's about 40% faster for n~10^7

Comment: Actually I'm wondering if `1/x * 1/x` would be faster still

Comment: OP, if you use this, be prepared to explain to your professor: 1) list/tuple comprehension 2) lists or tuples, if you haven't covered that topic yet 3) The `range()` function, if you haven't covered that yet.

Comment: If you really want to code-golf this, you can just do a one-liner: `print("the sum is:" , sum(x**-2 for x in range(1, int(input("n: "))+1)))` but you won't be making any friends if you tried to pull that in the real world.

Comment: @JussiNurminen yeah I think it is, about 4%

Comment: @JNevill: Are there any lists or tuples in this code?

Comment: @FredLarson You're right. I was mistakenly thinking the `sum` was acting on a tuple defined by the parens, but in fact the the `sum()` function itself works on iterables. It's all iterables under the hood so maybe the better warning is "Don't use this unless you are prepared to explain iterables to your profressor". :)

Comment: @JNevill: Yes, I like that better.

Answer (score 0):

Just

`print(3.14159**2/6)`

It will be approximately correct, at least for large `n`.